# How to trigger CMake reconfiguration from a target?

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have the following setup:

```
- build/
    - conanbuildinfo.cmake   (generated)
- conanfile.py
- CMakeLists.txt
```

A `conan` command is ran before CMake, generating conanbuildinfo.cmake. This contains include paths etc. to be used during the compilation later. If I change the conanfile, I want to trigger conan again and a re-run of CMake from the generated ninja build. I have a script that can call conan and it updates everything properly. However, this happens after CMake was ran and even though conanbuildinfo was changed, CMake won't run once more. This causes ninja to "not see" the changes in the dependency graph, so it doesn't rebuild everything it has to rebuild. That means I have to run `ninja` twice to get everything to update. The way I trigger the reconfigure currently is like this:

```
set(DS_CONFIG_INDICATOR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ds_configured)

add_custom_command(
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/conanfile.py
  OUTPUT ${DS_CONFIG_INDICATOR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env --unset=PYTHONPATH ${PYTHON_BINARY} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/common/reconfigure.py ${DS_CONFIG_INDICATOR} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Checking if reconfigure is needed"
  USES_TERMINAL
)

add_custom_target(ConanReconfigure
  DEPENDS ${DS_CONFIG_INDICATOR}
)
```

Is there a way to trigger a reconfigure after this script was ran?

I tried using the following without any success:

- [CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html)
- Running cmake from the reconfigure.py script
- Touching the main CMakeLists.txt from the reconfigure.py script
- Using execute_process to run the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) work?

It seems to me like this should work if you use [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) (*not* `add_custom_command`) to run conan/`reconfigure.py` before any of the CMake logic that depends on its output, *combined with* adding the input files of that command to [`CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html).

Trying to run something *before* CMake won't work... but you don't need to do that, anyway. I think your problem is that you are trying to solve the wrong question. Instead, look at it as a) you want to run something *during* CMake's execution, and b) you want to re-run *CMake* if your "conanfile" changes. Re-running CMake will re-run conan.

Comment: execute_process is only executed if cmake runs, so it won't run e.g. if there are no changes to the CMakeLists. Which is the typical scenario. `conanfile` changes (e.g. because of a git pull), developer re-runs ninja and expects to update & rebuild everything necessary. I will try combining CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS with execute_process though, because I didn't think of that last time.

Comment: So I tried it and indeed, the key was to have `${DS_CONFIG_INDICATOR}` listed in the CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS list (and not conanfile.py as I previously thought). I still use `add_custom_command` because I need `USES_TERMINAL` and that doesn't work with `execute_process`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work, or not; with `add_custom_command`, CMake will run to completion (presumably using "old" value in the generated file?). If you need `USES_TERMINAL` in order to use *stdin* at CMake time, um... that sounds like a feature request. Otherwise, I'm not sure why you think you need `USES_TERMINAL`?

Comment: It does work and no, I don't need it for input. I'm running a program that requires a real terminal with locale for running, and without USES_TERMINAL cmake runs it in a weird way that makes it crash.